# Why is reduce working this way?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I wrote a function to fulfil the following criteria:

"Write a function that, given a string, produces a map of the indexes of all characters. For example, 
indexes("Mississippi") should return a map associating 'M' with the set {0}, 'i' with the set {1, 4, 7, 10}, and 
so on."

But why is the first value of `i` `1` in my implementation, thus chopping off the `M`?

```js
var s = 'Mississippi';

function indexes(s) {
  var acc = {};

  return s.split('').reduce(function(p, c, i) {
    if (!acc[c]) {
      acc[c] = [i];
    } else {
      acc[c].push(i);
    }

    return acc
  });
}
console.log(indexes(s)); // Object {i: Array[4], s: Array[4], p: Array[2]}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce the `M` is stuck in the `previousValue` parameter

Comment: `i = 1` because of: "The first time the callback is called, previousValue and currentValue can be one of two values. If initialValue is provided in the call to reduce, then previousValue will be equal to initialValue and currentValue will be equal to the first value in the array. **If no initialValue was provided, then previousValue will be equal to the first value in the array and currentValue will be equal to the second**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't specified an initial value for the accumulator, and so the first call to your callback has the first **two** entries in your array (e.g., `p` will be `"M"` and `c` will be `"i"`), but you're not using `p`, so you end up missing the `"M"`.

Not providing an initial value is useful when you're doing a straight sum (for instance), but for *this* sort of thing, I find the easiest way to use `reduce` to provide that initial value, like so:

```js
var s = 'Mississippi';

function indexes(s) {
  // Note: No `acc` here
  return s.split('').reduce(function(p, c, i) {
    // Note: Using `p` here
    if (!p[c]) {
      p[c] = [i];
    } else {
      p[c].push(i);
    }

    return p;
  }, {});
  // ^^-- Initializing the accumulator here
}
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(indexes(s))); // {"M":[0],"i":[1,4,7,10],"s":[2,3,5,6],"p":[8,9]}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you preferred to keep using the external `acc` instead, I'd probably use `forEach` rather than `reduce`.